# Acessing google Drive API with wsl using python - Error 404

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-drive-api, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to acess a shared drive with my account in gmail.
I want to do it using wsl and running a python  file, so i can work with the files using a model developed in python.

I did configure an API and tryed using an API key, using a ID client OAuth and then with a service account.
Ialways get the same error. "HttpError 404"

That means the drive ID is wrong, but it is not.
Up next is one of my trys .

I believe the problem would be the windows firewall. That doesant like wsl at all.

This is what i was trying. I got this with GPT, and was trying a diferent scope.

The goal was just print the file names as i was navigating in the drive

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2 import service_account

# Define o ID do drive compartilhado
shared_drive_id = 'xxxxxcensuredxxxxx'   

# Define as credenciais do serviço a partir do arquivo JSON
credentials_path = '/home/flora_sauer/credenciais.json'
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(credentials_path, scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'])

# Constrói o serviço do Google Drive
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

# Obtém a lista de arquivos no drive compartilhado
results = drive_service.files().list(corpora='drive', driveId=shared_drive_id, includeItemsFromAllDrives=True, supportsAllDrives=True).execute()

# Itera sobre os arquivos e imprime seus nomes
for file in results['files']:
    print(file['name'])
```

Comment: Just to be clear. It is a shared drive, and i have acces. Inside this drive we have a lot of diferent folders, with .wav files and .txt. And i can acess all of them.

Comment: About `It is a shared drive, and i have acces.`, in this case, does your service account can access to your shared Drive mean? And, can you provide the detailed error message of `HttpError 404`?